# Do Java8 lambdas maintain a reference to their enclosing instance like anonymous classes?

Tags: lambda, java-8, retrolambda

[We know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054360/do-anonymous-classes-always-maintain-a-reference-to-their-enclosing-instance/20647717#20647717) that anonymous classes maintain a reference to their enclosing instance and that this can lead to context leaks on Android.

Since [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) backports lambdas to Java7, it could be worth a try.

[It seems](http://slides.com/yaroslavheriatovych/frponandroid#/6/5) that Java8 lambdas do not have this problem, but I can't find any official information on that.

Any clue?

Comment: Are you asking about regular lambdas or the bytecode produced by Retrolambda? If you're asking about regular lambdas, what does Retrolambda have to do with the question?

Comment: From my understanding, retrolambda use Java8 to produce bytecode, and the answer may be valid for both.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Lambda expressions and method references capture a reference to `this` only if required, i.e. when `this` is referenced directly or an instance (non-`static`) member is accessed.

Of course, if your lambda expression captures the value of a local variable and that value contains a reference to `this` it implies referencing `this` as well…

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. Any reference?

Comment: You can read [this document §7](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27524543/2711488) following the links…

Answer (score 24):

Here is some info.

From the following link http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html:
This has a beneficial implication for memory management: while inner class instances always hold a strong reference to their enclosing instance, lambdas that do not capture members from the enclosing instance do not hold a reference to it. This characteristic of inner class instances can often be a source of memory leaks (the so-called lapsed listener problem)

You can also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html
from the text:
Nested class: Use it if your requirements are similar to those of a local class, you want to make the type more widely available, and you don't require access to local variables or method parameters.

Use a non-static nested class (or inner class) if you require access to an enclosing instance's non-public fields and methods. Use a static nested class if you don't require this access.