# this pointer escape in Java

Tags: java, pointers

When reading < Java Concurrency in Practice >, there's an example saying that the following code snippet will lead to `this` pointer escape in the constructor method. But I'm not sure what exactly does it mean, since I couldn't see any `this` reference in the source code of `ThisEscape` constructor method. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
public class ThisEscape {
    public ThisEscape(EventSource source)   {
        source.registerListener(
            new EventListener() {
                public void onEvent(Event e)    {
                    doSomething(e);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The anonymous inner class closes over a reference to `this` and implicitly uses it in the call to `doSomething` which I assume is intended to be an instance method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`EventListener` object is created from an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) and will have access to `ThisEscape.this` reference. Because of that the `this` pointer "escapes" the scope of the class it belongs to and will be accessible in other places like `EventListener`.

Even worse this whole thing happens before `ThisEscape` is fully constructed so the `doSomething()` method can potentially be called before the constructor finishes if the event is dispatched and handled by another thread.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's written in "< Java Concurrency in Practice >" but you can read [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html) article's "`Don't implicitly expose the "this" reference`" section which explain it well using same example/concept.

Basically this example is about **"implicitly"** exposing the `this` reference, and in the example it happens because **"non-static" inner classes maintain an implicit copy of the this reference of their parent object**. So, in your example, under multi-threading scenarios, it is possible that `doSomething(e)` method can get called even before object creation is completed.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054360/do-anonymous-classes-always-maintain-a-reference-to-their-enclosing-instance) answer explains how inner class maintains an implicit reference to parent class.